# Fetch and update data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to update a column in my table and fetch that data in realtime.
This is my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var change = function(){
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",                                   
  url: 'update.php',                          
  data: "",                        
  success: function(data) 
  {
    $("#msg").html("Succes");
  } 
});
}
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',                  
  data: "",                        
  dataType: 'json',             
  success: function(data)          
  {
    var id = data[0];              
    var vname = data[1]; 
    var user = data[2];         
    $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname+"<b>user: </b>"+user); 
  } 
});
  </script>
  <button id="submit" onclick="change();">
    Update
  </button>
  <span id="msg">msg</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is api.php

```
<?php 
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "root"; 
    $db_pass = ""; 
    $db_name = "youtube";
    $myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name") or die ("could not 
connect to mysql");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM variables";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sql);         
    $array = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);                      
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

And this is update.php

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "root"; 
    $db_pass = ""; 
    $db_name = "youtube";
    $myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
    $update = "UPDATE variables set newuser=0";
    $result = mysqli_query($myConnection,$update);
?>
```

My table has three columns id,name and newuser. Default value of new user is 1. Whenever i click the button it changes to 0 and it is updated in the database. But what should i do to display that updated value in newuser column in my html page after I click the button? I need to update and fetch that data in realtime. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I would just add a bit of code to the `success()` function after you've called `update.php`, to update the specific page element that contains the `new-user` value, like you do with your `success` message. It would make sense to check that it actually got updated by perhaps looking at the value of `$result` and signalling back to the calling JS. At the moment you don't know if it was successful or not. How does `update.php` know _which_ user it is resetting the status of? Your code will just update _all_ users.

Answer (score 0):

```
As per your functionality update has to happen first then retrieving of the data. Your code first calls the update, it acts as asynchronous and by the time it updates and return  the next ajax request response might come and your value of newuser can be still 1. Try changing your code in the below way.
var change = function(){
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",                                   
  url: 'update.php',                          
  data: "",                        
  success: function(data) 
  {
    $("#msg").html("Succes");
    // Retrive the data 
                $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'api.php',                  
              data: "",                        
              dataType: 'json',             
              success: function(data)          
              {
                var id = data[0];              
                var vname = data[1]; 
                var user = data[2];         
                $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname+"<b>user: </b>"+user); 
              } `enter code here`
            });
  } 
});
}
```